# Convert PDF to Image Batch

Tags: c#, image, pdf

I am working on a solution where I can convert pdf files to images. 
I am using the following example from codeproject:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317700/Convert-a-PDF-into-a-series-of-images-using-Csharp?msg=4134859#xx4134859xx

now I tried with the following code to generate from more then 1000 pdf files new images:

```
using Cyotek.GhostScript;
using Cyotek.GhostScript.PdfConversion;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RefClass_PDF2Image
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string outputPath = Properties.Settings.Default.outputPath;
            string pdfPath = Properties.Settings.Default.pdfPath;

            if (!Directory.Exists(outputPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Der angegebene Pfad " + outputPath + " für den Export wurde nicht gefunden. Bitte ändern Sie den Pfad (outputPath) in der App.Config Datei.");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Output Pfad: " + outputPath + " gefunden.");
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(pdfPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Der angegebene Pfad " + pdfPath + " zu den PDF Zeichnungen wurde nicht gefunden. Bitte ändern Sie den Pfad (pdfPath) in der App.Config Datei.");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PDF Pfad: " + pdfPath + " gefunden.");
            }


            Pdf2ImageSettings settings = GetPDFSettings();

            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan span;

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Extraktion der PDF Zeichnungen wird gestartet: " + start.ToShortTimeString());
            Console.WriteLine("");

            DirectoryInfo diretoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pdfPath);
            DirectoryInfo[] directories = diretoryInfo.GetDirectories();

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Es wurden " + directories.Length + " verschiedende Verzeichnisse gefunden.");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            List<string> filenamesPDF = Directory.GetFiles(pdfPath, "*.pdf*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFullPath(x)).ToList();
            List<string> filenamesOutput = Directory.GetFiles(outputPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFullPath(x)).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Es wurden " + filenamesPDF.Count + " verschiedende PDF Zeichnungen gefunden.");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            List<string> newFileNames = new List<string>();
            int cutLength = pdfPath.Length;


            for (int i = 0; i < filenamesPDF.Count; i++)
            {
                string temp = filenamesPDF[i].Remove(0, cutLength);
                temp = outputPath + temp;
                temp = temp.Replace("pdf", "jpg");
                newFileNames.Add(temp);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < filenamesPDF.Count; i++)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(newFileNames[i]);
                if (!fi.Exists)
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(fi.DirectoryName))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(fi.DirectoryName);
                    }

                    Bitmap firstPage = new Pdf2Image(filenamesPDF[i], settings).GetImage();
                    firstPage.Save(newFileNames[i], System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    firstPage.Dispose();
                }

                //if (i % 20 == 0)
                //{
                //  GC.Collect();
                //  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                //}
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static Pdf2ImageSettings GetPDFSettings()
        {
            Pdf2ImageSettings settings;
            settings = new Pdf2ImageSettings();
            settings.AntiAliasMode = AntiAliasMode.Medium;
            settings.Dpi = 150;
            settings.GridFitMode = GridFitMode.Topological;
            settings.ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Png24;
            settings.TrimMode = PdfTrimMode.CropBox;
            return settings;
        }
    }
}
```

unfortunately, I always get in the Pdf2Image.cs an out of memory exception. here the code:

```
public Bitmap GetImage(int pageNumber)
{
  Bitmap result;
  string workFile;

  //if (pageNumber < 1 || pageNumber > this.PageCount)
  //    throw new ArgumentException("Page number is out of bounds", "pageNumber");

  if (pageNumber < 1)
      throw new ArgumentException("Page number is out of bounds", "pageNumber");

  workFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

  try
  {
    this.ConvertPdfPageToImage(workFile, pageNumber);
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(workFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        result = new Bitmap(stream); // --->>> here is the out of memory exception
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
    }

  }
  finally
  {
    File.Delete(workFile);
  }

  return result;
}
```

how can I fix that to avoid this exception?

thanks for any help,
tro

Comment: yes, that's what I do: firstPage.Dispose();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this is worth it for you, but it appears that you can do what you want without having a Bitmap in the middle.  PdfToImage has this code in it:

```
public void ConvertPdfPageToImage(string outputFileName, int pageNumber)
{
  if (pageNumber < 1 || pageNumber > this.PageCount)
    throw new ArgumentException("Page number is out of bounds", "pageNumber");

  using (GhostScriptAPI api = new GhostScriptAPI())
    api.Execute(this.GetConversionArguments(this._pdfFileName, outputFileName, pageNumber, this.PdfPassword, this.Settings));
}
```

which writes a file for you where you want it.  Why not just call that method directly instead of reading the image back in and writing it back out?

Comment: great! that was exactly what I'm looking for! thumps up

Answer (score 2):

This might not be answering your question directly, but could still be useful: Imagemagick provides a simple way of creating images from pdfs in batch mode

Single pdf file to many jogs:

```
convert -geometry 1024x768 -density 200 -colorspace RGB test.pdf +adjoin test_%0d.jpg
```

or if you want to process many pdf files:

```
mogrify -format jpg -alpha off -density 150 -quality 80 -resize 768 -unsharp 1.5 *.pdf
```

(The settings should obviously be adapted to your needs :) )

To do this programmatically in C# you could use the .NET imagemagick wrapper
http://imagemagick.codeplex.com

Answer (score 2):

Add **using** for your resulted bitmap

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(workFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (Bitmap result = new Bitmap(stream))
{
...
}
```

Comment: This solution looks more elegant than just dispose.

Comment: **Using** wraps the enclosed block in a try/finally that calls **Dispose** in the finally block. This ensures that **Dispose** will be called even if an exception occurs. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984336/net-using-using-blocks-vs-calling-dispose)