# If an exception occurs inside a "using" block, is the Dispose method called?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dispose, using

In C#, if an exception occurs inside a "using" block, does the Dispose method get called?

Comment: YES.................................

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10984354/1344

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes it will get called.

`using` translates into `try-finally` block, so even in case of recoverable exception `Dispose` gets called.

See: [using statement C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.

Consider `SqlConnection` which implements `IDisposable` interface, so the following:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
    //some work
}
```

Would get translated into

```
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring");
    try
    {
        //somework
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
            ((IDisposable)conn).Dispose(); //conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```