# does transactionscope get properly disposed?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm finding a possible issue in our code base where the developer forgot to wrap the contents of a `using` statement with curley braces:

```
        using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(Transaction.Current))
            try
            {
                RecordUserConnectionCore(context, userName);
                transactionScope.Complete();
            }
            catch
            {
                transactionScope.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
```

**Does the try/catch get executed inside of the using statement? Is the transactionScope properly disposed?**

Please note that this question is in regards to wether the try/catch block is executing inside of the using context. I ask because there are no braces surrounding the try/catch code.

Comment: You don't need try-catch inside transaction to manage completeness of the transaction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using block vs IDisposabe.Dispose()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984336/using-block-vs-idisposabe-dispose)

Comment: my question is specifically in regards to usage of the curley braces NOT about how using /idisposable works

Comment: Should there be braces there to clearly convey what's intended to be part of the using block? IMO, yes, of course. Is the try/catch part of the using block in this circumstance? Yes. And the `Dispose()` call in the catch is redundant. Which means the whole try/catch block is completely meaningless because all it's doing (aside from the unnecessary Dispose() call) is rethrowing the exception.

Comment: When there are no curly braces ONLY the next statement will be the body of the block of code. In this case, the body is TRY/CATCH. But in your example you really don't need all that overhead. You are using try/catch to manage the transaction scope and then just rethrowing the original error. You might as well just remove the try catch and put both statements as the body inside the USING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Try/Catch is executing inside of the using block. Your code is exactly the same as if you had the following:

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(Transaction.Current))
{
      try
      {
           RecordUserConnectionCore(context, userName);
           transactionScope.Complete();
      }
      catch
      {
          transactionScope.Dispose();
          throw;
      }
}
```

One of the reasons you can know that this is true is because the

```
transactionScope.Dispose();
```

line compiles.

Answer (score 2):

After re-reading, I realized that I missed the actual question.

Yes, the `try/catch` is "within" the `using` block, even though the `using` statement doesn't have braces.

If a block doesn't have braces, then implicitly the block only includes the very next statement *or block*.

So using another example, you could do this:

```
if(x = 1)
{
    try{}
    catch{}
}
```

or this

```
if(x=1)
try{}
catch{}
```

and both are exactly the same.

For readability, I'll usually add the braces anyway. I think it's a little bit clearer and someone who doesn't know that detail of syntax won't be confused.

---

Yes, in your code the `TransactionScope` always gets disposed.

By putting it in a `using` block *and* calling `Dispose`, `Dispose` gets called twice if there's an exception. It gets called once in the `catch` block and again with the end of the `using` block. (That won't throw an exception, but it's unnecessary.)

The `using` block means that `transactionScope` already gets disposed even if there's an exception. So you could just do this:

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(Transaction.Current))
{
    RecordUserConnectionCore(context, userName);
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```